# How do you read an image from the Categories table in the Northwind database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, image

In SQL Server 2005, how do you read an image from the `Categories` table in Northwind?
I can upload my image to my own database and display it from there, but I can't display an image from `Categories` table in Northwind.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: you might want to re-phrase "Show me the code"....

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/efca2899-d8c7-49f6-ae6c-4934387b6177/) is what you're looking for (VB.NET code) - official support article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316887/en-us).